# How to get xml by mybatis in Spring project?

Tags: xml, spring, mybatis

I should unload data from oracle and the table contains many columns and one of them is a column containing XML (SYS.XMLTYPE). With all the other fields, I have no problems, I don't really understand how to unload this xml into an object in mybatis along with all other fields. For example, there is an entity Student and it has two fields. The name and the second is xml, in which the rest of the fields. How do I get this to work in spring and mybatis? And how, after receiving the xml, unload from it the values ​​of the fields that are inside. That is, there can be 3-4 fields in xml and I only know the name of these fields. How can I get the value after getting the field name?

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: MyBatis has a built-in type handler for `SQLXML` type, so getting a `String` out of `SQLXML` column should not be a problem. There are many ways to parse XML. This [article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-xml) may be a good start point. Parsing XML can be done after retrieving the result from MyBatis, or using [`ResultHandler`](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html#sqlSessions).

Comment: can you show example, please? i cant solve that problem.

Comment: getting data from xml is not problem. i did it, but cant get xml field with another fiels together

Comment: i get null value by SQLXML

Comment: There is nothing special, but [here](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-66277905) you are.

Comment: it solved my problem, thanks. i count found correct xdb dependency

Comment: Glad to know it helped! =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this dependency solved my problem

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.database.xml</groupId>
  <artifactId>xdb</artifactId>
  <version>21.1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```